# QDoc can generate documentation,but content is not full

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qdoc

I want to generate documentation with QDoc and I tried as the QDoc guide told. I can get documentation, but it's not complete.

I tried both on:

- qt 5.11.3, llvm 6.0.1, windows 10
- qt 5.12.3, llvm 6.0.1, ubuntu 16.04

but it's all the same.

Here is the code:

**project.qconconf**

```cpp
headerdirs  = .
sourcedirs  = .
exampledirs = .
imagedirs   = ./images

sources.fileextensions = "*.cpp *.qdoc *.mm *.qml"
headers.fileextensions = "*.h *.ch *.h++ *.hh *.hpp *.hxx"
examples.fileextensions = "*.cpp *.h *.js *.xq *.svg *.xml *.ui *.qhp *.qhcp *.qml"
examples.imageextensions = "*.png *.jpeg *.jpg *.gif *.mng"

outputdir   = html
outputformats = HTML
```

**mainwindow.cpp**

```cpp
/*!
 * \class MainWindow
 * \brief mainwindow for ui .
 */

/*!
  constructor
 */
MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
}

/*!
  destructor
 */
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}

/*!
  function test
 */
bool MainWindow::test() const
{
    return test_;
}

/*!
  function setTest
 */
void MainWindow::setTest(bool test)
{
    test_ = test;
}
```

After I execute command "qdoc proect.qdocconf",warning as follows:

> .../mainwindow.cpp:4: (qdoc) warning: Class MainWindow has no
>   \inmodule command; using project name by default:
>   .../mainwindow.cpp:9: (qdoc) warning: Cannot tie this documentation to
>   anything [I found a /*! ... */ comment, but there was no topic command
>   (e.g., '\fn', '\page') in the comment and no function definition
>   following the comment.]

I got two files: ".index" and "mainwindow.html"

"mainwindow.html":

> MainWindow
>   Contents
>   Detailed Description
>   MainWindow Class
>   mainwindow for ui interface.

More...

> Detailed Description
>   mainwindow for ui interface.

Seems like it can't get any other info except "\class".

Does anyone know what might cause the documentation to not be generated?